# How to generate client PHP code for SOAP using SOAP UI?

Tags: php, soap, client

Googling I've found this article:

http://java.dzone.com/tips/generating-client-java-code

It talk about how to generate a "JAVA" code with SOAP UI client, but what I need is to generate code php with soap UI or other resource.

Is this possible? exist any other resource to make it work that?

thank you for your answers..

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

soapUI will not generate PHP code.

Fortunately, in PHP there often isn't a need to generate proxy classes.  Instead, use [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) and simply call the SOAP methods you need outright.  You can find simple examples at [various](https://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/simple-php-soap-example/) [blogs](http://devzone.zend.com/25/php-soap-extension/#Heading5).

If the service with which you're interacting uses lots of complex types, then you may indeed want to [auto-generate some PHP code](http://www.mehtanirav.com/wsdl-to-php-generate-php-code-from-a-wsdl-file/) and make use of SoapClient's **classmap** option.